# How to build generic tree datastructure with ABAP OO

Tags: data-structures, tree, abap

I want to build a tree datastructure in ABAP. My key requirement is the possibility to use generic objects as node for the tree.

I Java it would look something like this:

```
public class MyTree<? extends TreeNode> {
(...)
}
```

My current approach would be to define a class `TreeNode` which is the super class of all possible nodes inside the tree.

Is there a more elegant way to realize generic types with ABAP OO? Or are there maybe datastructures shipped with SAP that I don't know of?

Answer (score 1):

Most operations on a `SORTED TABLE` have performance characteristics like a binary tree. I am pretty sure that the internal implementation of sorted tables is some flavor of binary trees (either that or [skip-lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)).

During my internship I recreated some typical data structures like linked lists or binary trees with ABAP objects and compared their performance to the equivalent native TABLE flavors - the native ones usually had the same complexity classes, but they always performed much faster. Unless you have some very special use-case which requires some exotic data structure, you should try to work with `TABLE`, `SORTED TABLE` or `HASHED TABLE`.

Comment: I need to work with data which is organized in a tree like model, i.e. the data is organized in a parent child manner. So I thought to keep my code clean and readable I implement something like a tree...

Comment: I agree. Use an internal table with NODE and PARENT fields (for example) to model your tree. It is better performance-wise and you will probably be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: When your data has a tree-like structure and the performance of searching through the tree is not very important, storing it in node objects might be a viable choice. But keep in mind that these will be hard to store in the database, because serializing and deserializing between tree nodes to table rows could become complicated.